# Overload operator for Complex Objects

Tags: c++, initialization, operators, operator-overloading, local-variables

I need to overload operator - for my complex type.I try to use that, but that's not helps.

```
myVector & operator -( myVector & iVect )
{
    int size = iVect.getSize();
    myVector temp( size );

    for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
        temp[ i ] = m_Vect[ i ] - iVect[ i ];

    return myVector( temp );
}
```

And i Try to overload copy constructor.

```
myVector( myVector & iVect ) : m_Vect( iVect.m_Vect ){}
```

I need this for using objects like `c = a - b;`

Comment: What is it that isn't working?

Comment: For one thing, don't return a reference to a temporary, that is Undefined Behaviour. Return a new object.

Comment: yes, this doesn't works.

Comment: I change return value to no reference. That works. Thank you.

Comment: You should think of const-correctness too: a subtraction should not modify either argument, so the prototype should be `myVector operator- (const myVector & iVect ) const` for a member, and `myVector operator-(const myVector& lhs, const myVector& rhs);` for a non-member.